# Download uploaded files MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have an upload function in an MVC 3 project which store the files in a database. I am trying to write code that will list all the files in the database with a link to download each one, but I have not having much success. Here is the controller code:

```
        public ActionResult Download(int id)
    {
        var db = GetDataContext();
        var file = db.UserFiles.First(f => f.ID == id);
        return File(file.Data.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", file.Name);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = GetDataContext();
        var files = db.UserFiles.Select(f => new FileViewModel { ID = f.ID, Name = f.Name });
        return View(files);
    }
```

I have created a view from the ActionResult Index and the code in the view is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Lesson", "Download", "Upload", new { id = 1 })
```

I have also created a class file called FileViewModel, which serves to prevent the data being retrieved from the database when the files are listed:

```
    public class FileViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in the download View where I will list the files, I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<DFPProductions_Default.Models.FileViewModel>
```

The error I'm getting when I click on the link is:
    The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Download(Int32)' in 'DFPProductions_Default.Controllers.UploadController'.

Please help me discover what I've done wrong.
Thanks,
Amy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be you are not sending any Id to the Controller. 
Try calling you action link:
`@Html.ActionLink("Lesson", "Download", "Upload", new { id = 1 }, null)`

Also, for future reference, you should keep the controller to a minimum, no interactions with the database.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. The error has changed now. It's highlighting this bit of code: 'code'return File(file.Data.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", file.Name)'code' from the controller. The error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Do you know why? Thanks :)

Comment: Try to change your code to `var file = db.UserFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == id);` and then do a `if(file != null)` before you return the File as you might not have any entries in your DB with that Id

Comment: Great, it's working now, thanks so much :) But how would I go about listing all the files in the database regardless of the ID? With a loop? What I really want to do is allow certain users (who are assigned roles) to see certain files. It's for a music school - so guitar students would only see guitar lessons for instance. Would I put the IsInRole code in the Download ActionResult? Thanks!